# Unable to load class 'com.android.aapt.Resources$ResourceTable'

Tags: android, kotlin, android-emulator

I ran my application on the Android emulator and it doesn't work because an error like this always appears..(Unable to load class 'com.android.aapt.Resources$ResourceTable'.

This is an unexpected error. Please file a bug containing the idea.log file.
), What should I do?

I looked for a solution to the problem on Google but couldn't find a solution

Comment: Cna you provide the entire error stack trace ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.